# When is the session abandoned during a typical session?

Tags: asp.net, session, sitecore

I'm trying to [figure out an issue I'm having with sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845461/can-i-still-access-a-sitecore-contact-facet-once-session-is-flushed). I'm wondering if my issue is basically a problem with their [reliance on `Session.Abandon()`](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2014/09/introducing-contact-facets.aspx):

> For performance reasons Sitecore only writes contact data to xDB *(this is mongo)* when
>   the session ends.

This logic seems somewhat flawed (unless I misunderstand how sessions are managed in Asp.Net).

- At what point (without explicitly calling `Session.Abandon()`) is the session flushed in this model? i.e. When will the `session_end` event be triggered?
- Can you guarantee that the logic will always be called or can
  sessions be terminated without triggering an `Abandon` event? for example when the app_pool is recycled.

I'm trying to figure this out as it would explain something that I'm experiencing, where the data is fine in session but is written intermittently into the mongoDb

Comment: I think you can end for it to write to mongo using :Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.EndVisit(false); Can you check if is working?

Comment: But how would I know when to trigger this event? This is the crux of my issue. I don't believe this is a good idea as the ending of a session is a very vague thing.

Comment: I also consider ending session is not a good choice.

Comment: pretty bad idea. This will interrupt the user experience ...

Comment: Re-phrased questions to be more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

I think that strategy for building the data in session and then flushing the data to MongoDb fits for xDb.

xDb is designed to be high volume so it makes sense for the data to be aggregated rather than constantly being written into a database table. This is the way DMS worked previously and doesn't scale very well.

The session end in my opinion is pretty reliable, and Sitecore give you various option for persisting session (inproc, mongo, SQL server), MongoDb and SQL Server are recommended for production environments. You can write Contact data directly to MongoDb by using the Contact Repository api but for live capturing of data you should use the Tracker api. When using the tracker api, as far as I am aware, the only way to get data into MongoDb is to flush the session.

If you need to flush the data to xDb for testing purposes then Session.Abandon() will work. I have a module here which you can use for creating contacts and then flushing the session, so you can see how reliable the session abandon is by checking in MongoDb.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/X/xDB_Contact_Creator.aspx

Comment: Do you have any information to back up the opinion that it's reliable?

Comment: Also its not a db, it's a nosql instance, its designed for high volumes, that's why twitter, etc use it.  Really I wanted to know if session abandon was reliable and why, so you've not answered my question

Comment: I've tested this myself and had no issues with the flush of data to MongoDb, if you're having issues then I suggest you contact Sitecore support . Do I have any evidence that it's reliable? No, but I don't think xDb would exist if the fundamental  part that gathers data was flawed.

Comment: I know it's not a db, I've never called it a db - xDb is Sitecore Terminology for the moving parts that include MongoDb and aggregation.

Comment: Think you're being a bit harsh, I've tried to answer each of your points.

Comment: I'm sorry but you haven't. I asked is it a good idea, you've say do yes but given no explanation, I then asked can the logic around abandon be guaranteed, u haven't answered this at all.

Comment: I don't want to waste any more mental energy on this as it's likely that this post will be deleted, but I'll leave with some points.

Comment: 1. xDB does not rely on Session Abandon - it taps into the the session_end event. the example you refer to uses Session.Abandon for testing purposes.

Comment: 2.Whether something is a good idea normally depends on the context - in the context of xDB where data is collected gradually and then flushed to MongoDB, session_end is appropriate - whether session end is reliable? - put another question on so for this. 3. Where I said "and rather than constantly being written into a database table" I was referring to Sitecore pre 8 in DMS where a SQL db was used for collecting analytics data.

Comment: You've **still** failed to answer the questions! My question **is** *"whether session end is reliable"*....Seriously man, the whole point of SO is to answer the question being asked. This isn't a forum of opinions. It's a Q&A site.

Comment: @Liam - To wrap it up. Session end is triggered on app pool recycle (it means the data will get flushed to mongo on session_end). The normal abandon time is based on a setting in web.config. You can find more information on the knowledge base - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/345947. Also keep in mind that it is sliding expiration - meaning that if the takes an action - the timer resets. All in all abandoning the user session is not a good approach, because I said on the question itself it disrupts the user journey :) Hope this answers your question

Comment: @nsgocev, that article is very useful, thank you.