# How can I implement collections of objects in a Sitecore facet?

Tags: c#, content-management-system, sitecore

[This article](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/contacts/create_a_custom_contact_facet) seems to suggest that it's possible but seems to skip over the crucial implementation of the collection itself. It lays out the rough structure:

```
public interface ICoordinate : IElement
{
    float Longitude { get; set; }
    float Latitude { get; set; }
}

public interface IPlace : IElement
{
    string Description { get; set; }
    ICoordinate Coordinate { get; }
}

public interface IPlaces : IFacet
{
    IElementDictionary<IPlace> Places { get; }
}
```

Just what I need a collection of objects. So how do I implment that?

```
[Serializable]
  internal class Coordinate : Element, ICoordinate
  {
    private const string LONGITUDE = "Longitude";
    private const string LATITUDE = "Latitude";

    public float Longitude
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetAttribute<float>( LONGITUDE );
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetAttribute( LONGITUDE, value );
        }
    }

    public float Latitude
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetAttribute<float>( LATITUDE );
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetAttribute( LATITUDE, value );
        }
    }

    public Coordinate()
    {
      this.EnsureAttribute<float>(LONGITUDE);
      this.EnsureAttribute<float>(LATITUDE);
    }
  }
```

that's the coordinate, what about the `Places`? How do I add new places? The article seems to be missing this information

Comment: Why do you add the question if you respond in same time? :)

Comment: To help others with the same problem! @SitecoreClimber [It's perfectly valid (and encouraged) to do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/217110). Thats why there is an "answer your own question" tick box

Comment: ..also the poor quality of that article annoyed me. It totally misses out the crucial elements..

Comment: The official documentation of xDB is lacking currently. But I have written a number of lengthy blogs how to achieve this and lots of other things that will help - https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/12/08/how-to-extend-sitecore-experience-database/

Comment: That would of acytually been very useful @JonathanRobbins. I did not find these though in my searching for an answer to this.

Comment: That's a shame, I'll add some keywords to hopefully raise it higher in the searches. :) What text did you search for?  If you don't mind you could add a link to the post for further reading

Comment: Oh, quite a few things, sitecore facet, facet collection, collection null, etc. etc. I've added a link in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after much playing about I managed to piece it together. The crucial (though not well explained) section of the article is:

> Register the attributes, collections, and dictionaries with the base
>   class in the constructor using the following helper methods:
>
> ```
> this.EnsureAttribute<TValue>( string name );
> this.EnsureElement<TElement>( string name );
> this.EnsureDictionary<TElement>( string name );
> this.EnsureCollection<TElement>( string name );
> ```

so a collection is ["Ensured"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32863078/542251) differently to an attribute. So the implementation (from the example) of the `Places` class would look something like:

```
[Serializable]
public Places : Facet, IPlaces
{
    private const string FIELD_PLACES = "Places";

    public Places()
    {
       this.EnsureDictionary<IPlace>(FIELD_PLACES);
    }


    public IElementDictionary<IPlace> Places 
    { 
      get
      {
          return this.GetCollection<IPlace>(FIELD_PLACES);
      }

    }
}
```

Notice the different Get(`this.GetCollection<IPlace>(FIELD_PLACES);`) and Ensure calls(`this.EnsureDictionary<IPlace>(FIELD_PLACES);`). If you don't do this your collection will be `null`. The `IPlace.Coordinate` will be set up in the same manner. By calling these it will instanciate the correct collections for you.

Adding is not strightforward (or explained) either. `IElementDictionary` does not expose an Add method. It does though expose a `Create()`. A quick look at this using a reflection tool and you can see that it creates an item and add's it to the Dictionary:

```
public TElement Create(string key)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(key, "key");
    TElement tElement = ModelFactory.CreateElement<TElement>();
    this.dictionary.Add(key, tElement);
    return tElement;
}
```

so adding to the Places dictionary goes something like:

```
IPlaces places = _contact.GetFacet<IPlaces>("name form XML config");
IPlace newPlace = places.Places.Create();
newPlace.Description = "test";
ICoordinate newCoord = newPlace.Coordinate.Create();
newCoord.Longitude = 0;
```

no need to save, etc. The persisting, etc. is handled internally.

You need to register all 3 "elements" but only the top most facet (`IPlaces`) needs to go into the `<entities>` collection of the XML. So the whole config looks something like:

```xml
<sitecore>
    <model>
      <elements>
        <element interface="Namespace.IPlaces, Dllname" implementation="Namespace.Places, Dllname" />
        <element interface="Namespace.IPlace , Dllname" implementation="Namespace.Place, Dllname" />
        <element interface="Namespace.ICoordinate, Dllname" implementation="Namespace.Coordinate , Dllname" />

      </elements>
      <entities>
        <contact>
          <facets>
            <facet name="name form XML config" contract="Namespace.IPlaces, Dllname" />
          </facets>
        </contact>
      </entities>
    </model>
  </sitecore>
```

[Subsequently I've seen this article](https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/12/08/how-to-extend-sitecore-experience-database/) which covers this and goes into additional details about custom data